# Docker Containers are not able to communicate

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

**I went into frontend and curl to backend and its works but from the browser its not working**

here is my docker-compose file :

```yaml
version: '1'

services:
  frontend:
    image: 'ccm-frontend'
    build: 
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.Dev
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - codecommunitymusic-network
    environment:
      NODE_OPTIONS: --max-old-space-size=4096
      NEXTAUTH_URL: http://frontend:3000
      __NEXT_PRIVATE_PREBUNDLED_REACT : next
      APP_URL: http://frontend:3000
      NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL: http://backend:8000
      BACKEND_URL: http://backend:8000
    depends_on:
      - backend

  backend:
    image: 'ccm-backend'
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    networks:
      - codecommunitymusic-network
    depends_on:
      - database
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME=admin
      - DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL=admin@example.com
      - DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=password
      - SECRET_KEY= 
      - DATABASE_NAME=postgres
      - DATABASE_USER=postgres
      - DATABASE_PASS=password
      - DATABASE_HOST=database
      - EMAIL_HOST_USER=hello@gmail.com
      - EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=demo_password
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app
    command:  > 
      sh -c "
      python manage.py makemigrations &&
      python manage.py migrate &&
      python manage.py runserver  0.0.0.0:8000"


  database:
    image: postgres:16-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres  
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres  
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - codecommunitymusic-network
    ports:
      - 5432:5432


networks:
  codecommunitymusic-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Frontend is unable to make api calls to backend I tried localhost and also tried service name but requests are getting failed

Error its gives me :

xhr.js:251     GET http://backend:8000/users/abhishek net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

I tried including them in same network also restarted the instance. I went into frontend and curl to backend and its works but from the browser its not working.

Comment: *"I went into frontend and curl to backend and its works but from the browser its not working"* This should be the first sentence in the question, not the last

Comment: The frontend application is running in a browser (even if its code is being served out of a container) and can't use Docker networking features.  I describe two approaches to resolving this in the linked question.

Comment: (You declare `version: '1'`, but Compose file version 1 didn't include a `services:` block and didn't support now-commonplace things like Docker networks.  Do you mean _e.g._ `version: '3.8'` for a current version of the Compose file format?)

Answer (score 1):

When you say "frontend" you should distinguish between the Node server and the browser: the Node server runs on Docker, the browser runs on your PC; the Node server is the frontend of "backend:8000" and the browser is the frontend of Node, so you can say that you have two frontends. From Node you can comunicate using "backend:8000" but not from the browser. If the JavaScript code running *on the browser* needs to call directly the backend you have to use the IP of the Docker server with port 8000.